# My loop is running twice and not giving the right answer any solution for this

Tags: javascript, algorithm, list, data-structures

** The maximum sum subarray problem consists in finding the maximum sum

> of a contiguous subsequence in an array or list of integers:
>   maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]) // should be 6: [4, -1,
>   2, 1] Easy case is when the list is made up of only positive numbers
>   and the maximum sum is the sum of the whole array. If the list is made
>   up of only negative numbers, return 0 instead.
>
> Empty list is considered to have zero greatest sum. Note that the

empty list or array is also a valid sublist/subarray.**

```
var maxSequence = function(arr) {
    // ...
    let max = 0;
    const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
    });
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (sorted[sorted.length - 1] >= 0 && sorted[0] >= 0) {
        let max = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            max += sorted[i];
        }
        return max;
    } else if (sorted[0] < 0 && sorted[sorted.length - 1] < 0) {
        console.log(0);
    } else {
        let halfLength = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
        let pivot = 0;
        let sequence = 0;
        let next = 1;
        while (pivot <= arr.length - 1) {
            if (arr[next] <= halfLength) {
                sequence += arr[next];
                next += 1;
            } else {
                sequence = 0;
                halfLength += 1;
                pivot += 1;
                next = pivot + 1;
            }

            if (pivot == arr.length - 2) {
                sequence += arr[next];
                next += 1;
                break;
            }

            if (sequence >= max) {
                max = sequence;
            }
        }
        console.log("the answer", max);
    }
};

maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]); //, 6)
```

> **The code return 12 instead of 6 any solution i have been trying for an hour now **

Comment: A quick Google search returns https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/, among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just test it for all combinations and see which one give you the best score.

```js
function maxSequence(data) {
  let result = {
    value: null,
    seq: null
  }

  let check = {
    pos: true,
    neg: true
  }

  data.forEach(e => {
    if (e > 0) check.neg = false;
    if (e < 0) check.pos = false;
  })

  if (check.pos) {
    return sum(data)
  } else if (check.neg) {
    return 0;
  }

  function sum(seq) {
    return seq.reduce((r, e) => r + e, 0)
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < data.length; j++) {
      const seq = data.slice(i, j + 1);
      const seqSum = sum(seq);

      if (result.value === null || seqSum > result.value) {
        result.value = seqSum;
        result.seq = seq;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(maxSequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]))
console.log(maxSequence([1, 5, 9, 1]))
console.log(maxSequence([-1, -2, -3, -4]))
```

Comment: There is a much simpler, and more efficient, solution.